# How can I scale and rotate a square to fit within a square at a user inputted angle?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, trigonometry, glm-math

I'm currently trying to draw a square inside a square recursively, which will fit inside its respective square. The user will input how many times the square will scale and rotate, and choose the angle.

For example, when inputted 5 divisions with a 45 degree angle, it will produce:

[Image scaled by sin(45) and rotated at a 45 degree angle 5 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj3gE.png)
[image]

Now this is alright, but it only works for the 45 degree angle. How would I get the scale of a different angle? Say a division of 5 is inputted at a 19 degree angle?

Below is my code right now (It is in OpenGL but its still a trig/math question):

```
glm::vec3 vector = transformObject(1.0f, Z_AXIS, 0.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
float scale = 1.0f;
float SinOfAngle = glm::sin(glm::degrees(inputtedAngle));
for (int i = 0; i < userInputTimes; i++)
{
    scale *= SinOfAngle;
    vector = transformObject(scale , Z_AXIS, inputtedAngle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    inputtedAngle += inputtedAngle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **its still a trig/math question** I'll answer mathematically.

[image]

No matter how the squares are rotated their central point will always be the same. This is an affine transformation question,

assume user provided an angle θ, repeated k times.

fix vector n that is the unit vector pointing upward.

1. fix vector v1 from the center to one corner.
2. rotate the vector v1 by θ degrees and you will get v1`
3. the scaling factor will be：float factor = glm::dot(v1, n) / glm::dot(v1`, n)
4. scale and rotate the original square and n by (factor, θ), you will get the red square in fig.2 // remember scale first then rotate, the order is very important here.

Repeat 1, 2, 3 by k times and you should be able to get that k rotated squares.

---

ps 1. The proof means if we project v1 and v1` to the vector n, the factor for both the vertical side and hypotenuse is the same due to similar triangles. so glm::dot(v1, n) / glm::dot(v1`, n) is a valid factor.

ps 2. Only the first iteration is dependent on the global frame, the rest operations all depend on the local frame generated by the previous iterations.

Comment: I'm a little confused when trying to understand this. Say vector.x is the length (1) of the squares sides. I have the length sides, I have the hypotenuse (sqrt((1 * 1 + 1 * 1)), and I have the angles (90, 45, 45). Not sure how I'm supposed to plug these numbers to get the scale. I have figured out that once you get the first scale, it just scales down by that much recursively. So for 45 degree rotation, scale is scale *= 0.707107 every iteration. For a 19 degree rotation it is scale *= ~0.785 every iteration.

Comment: @JohnCannatoid in that case, v1 will be (-0.5, 0.5), and the rotated v1’ will be (0, sqrt(2)/2), n will be (0,1). By plugging in numbers you get dot(v1, n) / dot(v1’,n) = 0.5 / (sqrt(2)/2) => 0.707107.

Comment: Where does the angle inputted by the user come into play in this equation? So for like 19 degree rotation? It seems that equation will always output a scale that works for a 45 degree rotation only

Comment: @JohnCannatoid the user input angle is theta

Comment: I've tried the formula you gave me, I'm wondering where to put theta into it? I've tried making two vectors. One is (-0.5, 0.5) and the other is (theta, sqrt(2)/2) and n is (0, 1). I then did the divided the two dot values. At any inputted angle, the answer was 0.707107 which won't work for a 19 degree rotation. If user inputs 19 as angle of rotation, it should give me an approximate scale of 0.785 though at any angle inputted I get 0.707107

Comment: This is my code right now: https://pastebin.com/V6YP5s7F

At user inputted angle 19.0f, output of "VAL" is still 0.707107.

Comment: @JohnCannatoid the theta value is to be used to generate the rotation matrix. Rot = [(cos(theta), -sin(theta)),(sin(theta), cos(theta))], the rotation matrix will rotate v1 vector to v1’, thus you can use these two vectors to calculate the scale. If you had no experience with these matrices I would suggest you to read https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html

Comment: @JohnCannatoid if I have a vector v1 = (-0.5, 0.5), and the theta value is 19 degrees, my rotation matrix will be [(cos(-19), -sin(-19)),(sin(-19),cos(-19))], using this matrix to rotate v1, you will get (-0.30997, 0.63554), using the formula for the scaling value, you will get dot((-0.5,0.5), (0, 1)) / dot((-0.30997, 0.63554), (0, 1)) = 0.78673

Comment: Negative angle because you are rotating clock-wise

Comment: I figured it out! Learning about rotation matrices plus the math you gave me worked perfectly. Thank you so much!